# Protocol with one delegate and many senders?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

I have the following situation of my app. Four child VCs need to have a data source delegate, which their root VC (they all share one root VC) must implement.

My question is - do I declare a protocol in each child VC and implement each protocol individually in the root VC, or is there a better way? Somehow define the protocol only once?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to declare 4 protocols in 4 child VC's.

Take only one protocol just like @elio.d said and implement that protocol method in your Root VC.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up doing just that. Declared a new protocol in another file, created a data source object in each child VC and implemented the protocol in the root vc. Works beautifully :)

Answer (score 1):

What about having each Child that Inherit from a controller that declare the protocol you need?

```
@protocol VCChildDelegate <NSObject>
 -(void) yourMethod;
@end

@interface WCChildAbstract : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic,assign> id<VCChildDelegate> delegate
@end
```